# Обработка данных в большом массив Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Дан большой массив, порядка 4млн элементов. Необходимо над каждым элементом произвести определенную операцию.

Сейчас код выполняется порядка 60 секунд. Как можно ускорить или с какой стороны лучше зайти?

```
val pix_gray = IntArray(4000000)
......
pix_gray.map { (0.299 * (it shr 16 and 0xff) + 0.587 * (it shr 8 and 0xff) + 0.114 * (it and 0xff)).toInt()}
```

Comment: многопоточность пробовали в каком-то виде?

Comment: не создавать копий (map создаёт копию, да ещё и `List` c `Integer` на JVM), а менять сам массив, если возможно

Comment: @Andrew не пробовал

Comment: @IR42 даже проход цикла занимает порядка 6 секунд. 200мс предел на выполнение

Comment: Тест на современном ноубуке (код перенёс на Java): 83ms. Как вы получаете 60s?

Comment: Три раза вычисляете `it shr 16 and 0xff`. Зачем?

Comment: Многопоточность используйте

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy android smartphone

Comment: Нужен более реалистичный пример, который можно запустить и измерить время. Сейчас нет данных, вычисления выглядят странно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy выглядит странно, так как пытаюсь сделать на чистом java. Если использовать специальные библиотеки(OpenCV), то все работает, как надо. Но не хочу тащить тяжелую библиотеку в приложение